# How to get parameters value in model from views form in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller

Here is my `new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for :simulation, url: simulations_path do |f|  %>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Name %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :'Rendering Option' %>
 <div class="Dropdown">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <%= select_tag(:is_random, options_for_select([['Random', true], ['No Opinion', false]], selected: :is_random )) %>
</div>
```

```
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 </div>
```

simulations_controller.rb

```
class SimulationsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @simulations = Simulation.all
 end

 def new
 end

 def create
   @simulation = Simulation.new(simulation_params)
   @simulation.save
   redirect_to @simulation
 end

 def show
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
 end
```

end

Simulation.rb (Model class)

```
class Simulation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Schema.rb

```
 create_table "simulations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.boolean  "is_random"
 end
```

I am not able to set the `:is_random` value in database while rest is fine. What I am doing wrong here? I checked the value in `sqlite` database and there was `null` entry in `is_random` column.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am newbie in ruby and just looking a way to start the development. Is that something wrong with the `select_tag`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *permit* attributes while doing mass assignment. You could write it as :

```
<%= f.select(:is_random, options_for_select([['Random', true], ['No Opinion', false]], selected: :is_random )) %>
```

or

```
<%= select_tag("simulations[:is_random]", options_for_select([['Random', true], ['No Opinion', false]], selected: :is_random )) %>
```

With your syntax, the value is inside the `params` hash as `{..., is_random: true,..}`, that's why inside the strong parameter filtering method you are not getting it. If you use now the suggested solutions, you will get it the value inside the `params` hash like `{..., simulations: { is_random: true,..}, ...}`.

You can inspect all these from the the **development.log** file, while making the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form object select method like bellow:

```
<%= f.select(:is_random, options_for_select([['Random', true], ['No Opinion', false]], selected: :is_random )) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `f.select` (suggested above) should fix your problem. If you look at the generated html, you will see this field with a name of "is_random". It should be "simulations[is_random]". When you pull the form field values from the params object like this `params[:simulations]` all form fields with names in the form of "simulations[name]" will be included. Using the form builder object names the form fields correctly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `<%= debug params %>` to inspect what's in params, it's very helpful.